# When editing code that is working on my production site, and testing on the developer site the exact same code will not run

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, interchange

To start, I am a beginner that has started working with my employer on their website. Adding small functions and features here and there. The issue I am coming across is, I am trying to add a reCaptcha to one of our payment pages and when I test the code taken directly from the production site in the developer environment there are features that no longer work. There are radio buttons that drop down when selecting a payment option for credit or debit to add the additional payment information that no longer works when on the developer site. This is the page I am working on: [here](https://www.binsons.com/payment.html) This is all before even adding the CAPTCHA. That part I did not have a problem with, it is matching the current functionality. I need it to work on the dev site before pushing changes to production. My company currently uses Interchange web-based application server. Here is some of the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
//payment type check
   var payType = $('input[name=paymentType]:checked', '#paymentForm').val();
   if( payType == null ) 
   { 
      alert('You have not selected a Payment Type') 
      return false; 
   }

   //credit card check
   if( payType == 'credit' ){
           if(IsEmpty(form.cc_type)) 
           { 
              alert('You have not entered a Credit Card Type') 
              form.cc_type.focus(); 
              return false; 
           } 
           if(IsEmpty(form.ccnum)) 
           { 
              alert('You have not entered a Credit Card Number') 
              form.ccnum.focus(); 
              return false; 
           } 
           if(IsEmpty(form.ccmo)) 
           { 
              alert('You have not entered a Credit Card Expiration Month') 
              form.ccmo.focus(); 
              return false; 
           } 
           if(IsEmpty(form.ccyr)) 
           { 
              alert('You have not entered a Credit Card Expiration Year') 
              form.ccyr.focus(); 
              return false; 
           }
           if(IsEmpty(form.cvv2_number)) 
           { 
           //   alert('You have not entered the Credit Card CVV2') 
           //   form.cvv2_number.focus(); 
           //   return false; 
           }
   }


   //checking account check
   if( payType == 'check' ){
    var chkType = $('input[name=checkingType]:checked', '#paymentForm').val();
    if( chkType == null ) 
    { 
       alert('You have not selected a Checking Type') 
       return false; 
    }
           if( !form.aba.value.match(/^\d{9}$/) )
           { 
              alert('Checking Routing Number must be 9 digits') 
              form.aba.focus(); 
              return false; 
           }
    else{
  var n=form.aba.value.split('');
  var chkSum = ( 3 * (parseInt(n[0]) + parseInt(n[3]) + parseInt(n[6])) + 
    7 * (parseInt(n[1]) + parseInt(n[4]) + parseInt(n[7])) + 
    (parseInt(n[2]) + parseInt(n[5]) + parseInt(n[8]))) % 10;
  if( chkSum != 0 ){ 
        alert('Checking Routing Number is invalid') 
        form.aba.focus(); 
        return false; 
  }
    } 
           if(IsEmpty(form.account)) 
           { 
              alert('You have not entered a Checking Account Number') 
              form.account.focus(); 
              return false; 
           } 
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

```js
var submitted = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
 try {
  $('#item_1_cost').priceFormat({
   prefix: '',
   thousandsSeparator: ''
  });
 } catch (e) { console.log(e); }
 
 $('#item_1_cost').val('[scratch form-item_1_cost]');

 $('.trimMe').focusout(function(){
  $(this).val( $.trim($(this).val()) );
 });
 
 var updateBilling = function () {
  if (!$("#sameAsShipping").is(":checked")) { return }
  $("#address").val( $("#saddr").val() );
  $("#city").val( $("#scity").val() );
  $("#state").val( $("#sstate").val() );
  $("#zip").val( $("#szip").val() ); 
 }

 $('.paymentTypeRadio').change(function(){
  $('#paymentCredit').hide();
  $('#paymentCheck').hide();
  var payType = $('input[name=paymentType]:checked', '#paymentForm').val();

  if(payType == "credit") {
   $('#pass_action').val('iTransact');
   document.paymentForm.action = "https://secure.paymentclearing.com/cgi-bin/rc/ord.cgi";  
   $('#paymentCredit').show();
   $('#aba').val('');
   $('#account').val('');
   $('#account_source').val('');
  } else if( payType == "check" ){
   $('#pass_action').val('@@MV_PAGE@@');
   document.paymentForm.action = "https://__SERVER_NAME__/@@MV_PAGE@@.html";
   $('#paymentCheck').show();
   $('#ccnum').val('');
   $('#ccmo').val('');
   $('#ccyr').val('');
   $('#cvv2_number').val('');
  }
 });

 $('.patientGroup').keyup(function(){ updateBilling() });
 $('.patientGroup').change(function(){ updateBilling() });
 $("#sstate").val("[scratch form-sstate]");
 $("#state").val("[scratch form-state]");
 
 
   // Add onclick handler to checkbox w/id checkme
   $("#sameAsShipping").click(function(){

  // If checked
  if ($("#sameAsShipping").is(":checked")) {
   $(".billingGroup").attr("readonly", true); 
     $("#first_name").val( $("#sfname").val() );
   $("#last_name").val( $("#slname").val() );
   updateBilling();  
  } else {
   $(".billingGroup").val('');
     $("#first_name").val('');
   $("#last_name").val('');
   $(".billingGroup").removeAttr("readonly"); 
  }
 });
}); // document ready 


var pop_window;
function popWin(pop_url) {
 pop_window = open(pop_url, 'package_info',',width=500,height=450,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes'); 
}   

function IsEmpty(aTextField) {
   if ((aTextField.value.length==0) || (aTextField.value==null)) return true;
 return false; // no need for else as if the statment is true this line will not run anyway
}       


function ValidateForm(form) {
 if( submitted == true ) { 
  alert("You have already submitted. Please wait while the page processes. Thank you.");
  return false;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>


<div class="mybinsonsform" style="width: 680px;">
 <input type="text" name="ccnum" id="ccnum" class="trimMe" VALUE="" size="30" maxlength="20">
</div>

<div class="mybinsonsform" style="width: 680px;">
 <select name="ccmo" id="ccmo">
  <option value="">Month</option>
  <option value="January">01 January</option>
  <option value="February">02 February</option>
  <option value="March">03 March</option>
  <option value="April">04 April</option>
  <option value="May">05 May</option>
  <option value="June">06 June</option>
  <option value="July">07 July</option>
  <option value="August">08 August</option>
  <option value="September">09 September</option>
  <option value="October">10 October</option>
  <option value="November">11 November</option>
  <option value="December">12 December</option>
 </select>
 <select name="ccyr" id="ccyr" style="width:70px;">
  <option value="">Year</option>
 </select>
</div>

<div class="mybinsonsform" style="width: 680px;">
 <input type="text" name="cvv2_number" id="cvv2_number" class="trimMe" value="" size="5" maxlength="5">
 <a href="[area href=special/cvv_pop]" target="package_info" onclick="popWin('[area href=special/cvv_pop]'); return false;">
  <small>Where is it?</small>
 </a>
</div>


<!-- Checking information -->
<div id="paymentCheck" style="display:none;">
 <div class="mybinsonsform" style="width: 680px;">
  <input type="radio" class="checkingTypeRadio" name="checkingType" value="acctChecking"> Checking Account
  <input type="radio" class="checkingTypeRadio" name="checkingType" value="acctSavings"> Savings Account
 </div>
 <div class="mybinsonsform" style="width: 680px;">
  <input type="text" name="aba" id="aba" class="trimMe" VALUE="" size="10">
 </div>
 <div class="mybinsonsform" style="width: 680px;">
  <input type="text" name="account" id="account" class="trimMe" VALUE="" size="10">
 </div>
</div>
```

If there is any more information I can provide please let me know. I appreciate any assistance! Thank you in advance!
-Tim

Comment: Hey Tim, could you provide more info on what's going wrong? - What's being output in the console

Comment: ... Plus, I just noticed, within your JS you've written, you have an invalid `return` statement, is that within a `function` or not? - You can only `return` from a `function` within traditional JS.

Comment: Here is what error pops up in Console:                        ReferenceError: $ is not defined[Learn More]
payment.html:25:1
<anonymous>
http://dev57.binsons.com/payment.html:25:1

Comment: Then in that case your jQuery isn't being defined soon enough, are you calling jQuery before you're running this code? - **Make** sure you are, because that could be causing this.

Comment: I added the full snippet above if you are able to advise further.

Comment: Look at the most recent edit I've made... At least there's no log errors?

Comment: The only issue I now see is that `priceFormat` is not a function, but I'm assuming you have that code elsewhere?

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V I made the changes, the error is no longer in Console. Thank you for looking into this I really appreciate it.

Comment: I've had a closer look, your markup is all screwed up, big time..... I mean you've done `INPUT TYPE=TEXT`.... Wut? .... I take it as you're **very** new to the job? - Don't take that as an insult, it's just a newbie mistake to make.

Comment: Very much so, also this is something that was written years ago so I am kind of getting thrown in to try and figure stuff out.

Comment: PM myself, I'll help you out! I remember the painful days of being a newbie, funny times.... But it's best to be thrown into the deep end, because you'll learn much at a much slower rate if they gently ease you in! ;)

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V will do! Thank you very much! You are right with that one...trial by fire.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that JQuery is being loaded? The piece of code responsible for showing/hiding the payment type fields is this:

```
$('.paymentTypeRadio').change(function() {
    $('#paymentCredit').hide();
    $('#paymentCheck').hide();
    var payType = $('input[name=paymentType]:checked', '#paymentForm').val();

    if (payType == "credit") {
        $('#pass_action').val('iTransact');
        document.paymentForm.action = "https://secure.paymentclearing.com/cgi-bin/rc/ord.cgi";      
        $('#paymentCredit').show();
        $('#aba').val('');
        $('#account').val('');
        $('#account_source').val('');
    } else if (payType == "check") {
        $('#pass_action').val('payment');
        document.paymentForm.action = "https://www.binsons.com/payment.html";
        $('#paymentCheck').show();
        $('#ccnum').val('');
        $('#ccmo').val('');
        $('#ccyr').val('');
        $('#cvv2_number').val('');
    }
});
```

It's using JQuery so perhaps it's not being loaded locally. Look for 404 errors in your console, or errors along the lines of `$ is not a function`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have looked it up in Console, it does show: payment.html:25 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at payment.html:25
(anonymous) @ payment.html:25
I am currently running through another reference about loading JQuery. Thank you for the direction.